# filtering out FileUtils.cp_r

Tags: ruby, cp

[FileUtils.cp_r](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r) does exactly what I need, but it's not able to filter out files by some pattern.

So, I would like to copy recursively a complex folder/files structure to another directory, but I'd like to only include files with `txt` extension. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUtils.cp_r Dir['**/*.txt'], target_dir
```

Comment: this fails:
$ mkdir -p a/b
$ touch a/a.txt a/b/b.txt
$ ruby -e "require 'fileutils'; FileUtils.cp_r Dir['a/**/*.txt'], 'foodir';"